# Is there a way to reduce redundancy in this code?

Tags: python

```
def pack_mesh_primitives(head_revision, compression_flags, mesh_primitives):
    packed_mesh_primitives = helpers.pack_int32(len(mesh_primitives), compression_flags)

    packed_mesh_primitives += bytearray(4)

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_resource(
        mesh_primitives[0].material, head_revision, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_resource(
        mesh_primitives[0].texture_alternatives, head_revision, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
        mesh_primitives[0].min_vert, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
        mesh_primitives[0].max_vert, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
        mesh_primitives[0].first_index, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
        mesh_primitives[0].num_indices, compression_flags
    )

    packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
        mesh_primitives[0].region, compression_flags
    )

    return packed_mesh_primitives
```

As you can see, there are a lot of redundant operations that are very similar. Is it possible to reduce the number of lines, and make this more compact?

Comment: all those lines aren't that similar... unless you have way more of these, I doubt it's worth trying to find a convoluted less readable way to save a couple of lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
def pack_mesh_primitives(head_revision, compression_flags, mesh_primitives):
    packed_mesh_primitives = helpers.pack_int32(len(mesh_primitives), compression_flags)
    packed_mesh_primitives += bytearray(4)

    mp_0 = mesh_primitives[0]
    items = [
        mp_0.materials,
        mp_0.texture_alternatives,
        mp_0.min_vert,
        mp_0.max_vert,
        mp_0.first_index,
        mp_0.num_indices,
        mp_0.region,
    ]

    for item in items[:2]:
        packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_resource(
            item, head_revision, compression_flags
        )
    for item in items[2:]:
        packed_mesh_primitives += helpers.pack_int32(
            item, compression_flags
        )

    return packed_mesh_primitives
```

*Thanks to @Julien in the comments for the annotations*

Comment: OP uses a mix of `helpers.pack_resource` and `helpers.pack_int32`. You could still make your approach work, but IMO it's not worth as it will likely not be any shorter and will certainly be less readable...

Comment: just repeat what he did but separating the 2 cases with 2 different loops...

Comment: you are right, I didn't notice it, I'll fix it

Comment: You could make items a list of tuples, first entry being the value, second being either a flag indicating with method to call, or a reference to the method itself that you just call.

Comment: I was just doing that, lol but with the function first hahaha

Comment: Second approach, as is, won't work because `head_revision` is only used for `helpers.pack_resource`. Again you could create unecessary complicated logic around that. But is it really worth it? IMO first approach is the only decent middle ground...

Comment: @Julien you are right again, didn't notice that too

Comment: (and you need to edit 1st appraoch too, to remove that `head_revision` in the second loop...)

Comment: I'm sure it can be done in a single for loop, but it will not worth it, that would make the code not clear at first glance